# Is there any Google Apps Script-like solution for running Python?

Tags: python, docker, google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have been using Google Apps Script for a while and quite like how it can easily be deployed on the web. My question is: **is there something similar to Google Apps Script for Python?** That is, some where we can create a Python application and run it completely online without having to package or containerize the app.

I am also looking at Docker and Google's App Engine right now but haven't been able to get a clear picture of pros and cons.

> Note: the practical application of what I am asking includes
>   manipulating large databases and let different clients run
>   manipulation scripts on their own cloud database themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad question, and not really the kind that Stackoverflow can help with. Trying reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

But to attempt to answer your question I need to break it down.

1) I assume that you are using the [script editor / IDE](https://www.google.com/script/start/) for developing / debugging GScript (aka JavaScript) code. And that is the simplest way to develop Google Apps Script (GAS) software. There is no alternative to this for python or any other language. However it is not obligatory to use the IDE to write software that uses the Google Apps Script APIs.

2) This [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/python), for example, is the Google Apps Script API quickstart that demonstrates how to use the GAS APIs from python.

3) However, to look at the big picture... you can regard GAS as an example of [Serverless Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serverless_computing), where the Google App Engine, AWS Lambda, and others (see the link) provide a straightforward environment for developing and deploying software without having to worry about packaging, containers, etc.

---

Docker might offer some advantages over traditional server deployment, but I would not regard it as an equivalent of serverless, as there is still a container environment to implement and manage.

---

The Pros and Cons of each are highly subjective, depending upon the nature of the problem your software needs to solve, and your starting point - if your business is already heavily into Azure or AWS then that might be the way to go. But if you require access to Google APIs for Maps, etc. then that might be the way to go, otherwise it probably boils down the specific services on offer, and cost.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the generic question. This is what I am looking for I believe since I want to understand what's out there.
I saw a lot of suggestions that combining Docker and App Engine may be beneficial but personally I think that might be redundant.
Thanks!